# Will time.Tick cause memory leak when I never need to stop it?

Tags: go

Consider the following code:

```golang
go func() {
    for now := range time.Tick(time.Minute) {
        fmt.Println(now, statusUpdate())
    }
}()
```

I need the for loop runs forever and never need to stop it.
Will this cause memory leak or not?

I knew if I ever need to break the for loop, it will cause memory leak. But what if I don't need to break the for loop?

> The doc says
>
> While Tick is useful for clients that have no need to shut down the Ticker, be aware that without a way to shut it down the underlying Ticker cannot be recovered by the garbage collector; it "leaks".

I just want to get it right.

Comment: The goroutine will always be running, and there won't be a memory leak

Comment: See also staticcheck's [SA1015](https://staticcheck.io/docs/checks#SA1015).

Comment: Something that would never go out of scope would never be eligible for GC anyway, so it logically cannot leak.

Comment: This totally can go out of scope when the go routine panics, though the program will terminate with exit status 2 right after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's see a definition of what a "memory leak" is, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak):

> In computer science, a memory leak is a type of resource leak that occurs when a computer program incorrectly manages memory allocations in a way that memory which is no longer needed is not released.

It's important to note that in the doc you quoted, it does not specifically mention a "memory leak", just a "leak" (meaning "resource leak"). The resources in question are not only the memory used by the ticker, but the goroutine that runs it. Because of this, I'll interpret this definition as applying to "resource leaks" more broadly.

As mentioned by the doc you quoted, `time.Tick` does not make it possible to release the ticker's resources.

So by this definition, if the ticker is no longer needed at any subsequent point in the program, then a resource leak has occurred. If the ticker is always needed for the remainder of the program after created, then it's not a leak.

Further in the Wikipedia definition, however, is this note:

> A memory leak may also happen when an object is stored in memory but cannot be accessed by the running code.

Again, `time.Tick` does not make it possible to release the ticker's resources.

So by this continued definition, you might say that the use of `time.Tick` is always a resource leak.

In practical terms, as long as you `range` over the `time.Tick` without `break`ing, you have reasonable assurance that the ticker is going to continue to be used for the remainder of the program, and there will be no "leak". If you have any doubts of if a ticker will be used forever, then use [`time.NewTicker`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker) and `Stop()` it appropriately:

```golang
go func() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Minute)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for now := range ticker.C {
        fmt.Println(now, statusUpdate())
        // some exception
        if (something) {
            break
        }
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `time.Tick()` function creates a ticker that consistently sends "ticks"
to the underlying Ticker's channel. The goroutine managing the ticker will
run indefinitely.

If the function in your program is intended to run forever,
using `time.Tick()` is appropriate. However, if the function may return under
certain circumstances, it can lead to a "goroutine leak" where the Ticker's
goroutine created by `time.Tick()` never stops.

A more controlled approach is to use `time.NewTicker` and manually manage
the ticker's lifecycle using the `Stop()` method. This ensures proper
termination of the ticker's goroutine when it's no longer needed:

```golang
ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)

<-ticker.C // receive from the ticker's channel

ticker.Stop() // cause the ticker's goroutine to terminate
```